# Combine two XML containers information in one SQL View

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, parent-child

since a while I'm looking for a join possibility in SQL to get the parent node of two xml containers joined.

Parent-node:

```
  select t.id,x."FA_SCHLUESSEL"  
   from xmldocs t  
      , xmltable('/Qualitaetsbericht/Organisationseinheiten_Fachabteilungen/Organisationseinheit_Fachabteilung/Fachabteilungsschluessel'  
          passing t.doc  
          columns 
          FA_Schluessel varchar2(12) path 'FA_Schluessel'
   ) x
```

Child-node:

```
 select t.id,x."OPS_301",x."ANZAHL"
   from xmldocs t  
      , xmltable('/Qualitaetsbericht/Organisationseinheiten_Fachabteilungen/Organisationseinheit_Fachabteilung/Prozeduren/Verpflichtend/Prozedur'  
          passing t.doc  
          columns 
          OPS_301 varchar2(12) path 'OPS_301'
       , Anzahl varchar2(40) path 'Anzahl'
   ) x
```

I'm quite frustrated with finding an answer to this. Any idea is highly welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
       d.*
FROM   XMLDocs x,
       XMLTable(
         '/Data'
         PASSING XMLQuery(
           'for $i in /Qualitaetsbericht/Organisationseinheiten_Fachabteilungen/Organisationseinheit_Fachabteilung/Prozeduren/Verpflichtend/Prozedur
            return <Data>
                     {$i/OPS_301}
                     {$i/Anzahl}
                     {$i/../../../Fachabteilungsschluessel/FA_Schluessel}
                   </Data>'
            PASSING doc
            RETURNING CONTENT
         )
         COLUMNS FA_Schluessel varchar2(12) path 'FA_Schluessel',
                 OPS_301       varchar2(12) path 'OPS_301',
                 Anzahl        varchar2(40) path 'Anzahl'
       ) d;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
  Extract(doc, '/Qualitaetsbericht/Organisationseinheiten_Fachabteilungen/Organisationseinheit_Fachabteilung/Fachabteilungsschluessel/FA_Schluessel' as FA_Schluessel,
  Extract(doc, '/Qualitaetsbericht/Organisationseinheiten_Fachabteilungen/Organisationseinheit_Fachabteilung/Prozeduren/Verpflichtend/Prozedure/OPS_301') as OPS_301,
  Extract(doc, '/Qualitaetsbericht/Organisationseinheiten_Fachabteilungen/Organisationseinheit_Fachabteilung/Prozeduren/Verpflichtend/Prozedure/Anzahl') as Anzahl
From xmldocs
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried and the result looks like this: 

FA_SCHLUESSEL OPS_301 ANZAHL
<FA_Schluessel>0100</FA_Schluessel> <FA_Schluessel>0200</FA_Schluessel> <FA_Schluessel>1500</FA_Schluessel> <FA_Schluessel>2300</FA_Schluessel> <FA_Schluessel>2400</FA_Schluessel> <FA_Schluessel>2600</FA_Schluessel>  -  -
<FA_Schluessel>2300</FA_Schluessel> <FA_Schluessel>0100</FA_Schluessel>  -  -
<FA_Schluessel>2300</FA_Schluessel>  -  -
<FA_Schluessel>0100</FA_Schluessel>  -  -

The Information on OPS_301 and Anzahl is not gshowing up